# DataContract works without DataContractAttribute (until obfuscation)

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I have the following layered JSON object represented by a `DataContract` that I can parse normally using `JavascriptSerializer`

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassOuter{
    [DataMember(Name = "stringProperty1")]
    public string stringProperty1 {get;set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "objectProperty")]
    public ClassInner objectProperty {get;set;}
}

//NOTE:No DataContract Attribute here!
public class ClassInner{
    [DataMember(Name = "stringProperty2")]
    public string stringProperty2 {get;set;}
}
```

But when I call

```
string inputText = "{\"stringProperty1\":\"Hello\",\"objectProperty\":{\"stringProperty2\":\"World\"}}";
ClassOuter myObject = new JavascriptSerializer().Deserialize<ClassOuter>(inputText);
Console.WriteLine(myObject.stringProperty2);
```

Everything works fine.

However, running the app through an obfuscator after building, stringProperty2 becomes null. *Can't say what obfuscator, sorry!

No warnings from CodeAnalysis.
I'm not very familiar with compilers, but here's my guess: the compiler recognizes the intent and makes the link internally, despite not having a `DataContract` attribute. However, it doesn't make some sort of internal marking, so the obfuscator feels free to jumble it and the link breaks. If it was just a block of continuous memory though, I would guess that things would break much harder than they do, not just becoming `null`

Can anyone verify or dispute my naive hypothesis?

(Adding in the `DataContract` attribute for `ClassInner` solves the problem, even with obfuscation!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone verify or dispute my naive hypothesis?

Unobfuscated, it will work without the `[DataContract]` because what happens is that the serializer will just fall back to not using attributes and serialize it by the property names only. They are identical to your attribute, so you don't notice this. You should be able to verify that by giving the `[DataMember]` that came without a proper `[DataContract]` another `Name` text, the serializer will still use the property name and ignore the attribute. Those attributes work as a pair. Set both or fall back to "none".

```
public class ClassInner
{
    // This is ignored because no [DataContract] was found
    [DataMember(Name = "nonexistentProperty")] 

    // This will still be set unobfuscated because the property name matches
    public string stringProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

So when you obfuscate it, the property names change. Without a `[DataContract]` to start with, the serializer will fall back to the attributes and find only random letter combinations that he cannot match with the input. Hence you will get `null`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much!